# How can I stop a GCP instance more quickly when it fails its health check?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have set up a [health check](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-managed-instances#monitoring_groups) to autoheal my managed instance group. When the health check fails for a particular instance it takes a while to stop so that it can be recreated.

Is there any way to speed up the stop procedure so that my instances are recreated more quickly?

Comment: It is not possible to speed up the stopping process. What is you use case for this? I would like to know the reason why you would want to achieve this speed up.

Comment: I run workshops which spin up infrastructure running mock workloads which are then subjected to availability problems to test the participants - one solution relies in part on GCP recreating instances so I don't want participants to have to wait as long for this to happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is something you probably did already: reduce the check interval and the timeout values. Other than that, this is the normal behavior of the GCE infrastructure. If there is anything you can optimize on your end, that would also reduce the time to recreate the VM.